# Make api calls parallel

Tags: boto3

I try to analyze multiple images with AWS Rekognition

In main function in a loop:

```
 with open("Test/frame%d.jpg" % count, "rb") as image:
    for face in RekognitionClass.detect_faces(image):
     =>Process result and write in DB
```

Rekognition Class:

```
def detect_faces(image, attributes=['ALL'], region="eu-west-1"):
rekognition = boto3.client("rekognition", region)
response = rekognition.detect_faces(Image={'Bytes': image.read()}, Attributes=attributes)
return response['FaceDetails']
```

But one api call takes about 2 second at least, and I would like to make more parallel calls if possible

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to make more parallel function calls using python multithreading and start the detect_faces function in a new thread each time.
It is important to use the boto3 client with sessions for the multithreading

Main:

```
p = Process(target=RekognitionClass.detect_process_faces, args= (count,))
  p.start()
```

in RekognitionClass:

```
def detect_faces(count, attributes=['ALL'], region="eu-west-1"):
session = boto3.session.Session()
rekognition = session.client("rekognition", region)...
```